# LINQ query performing very slow on even small collections

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0

I have a very odd problem where my LINQ query performs so so slow. The code is as following:

```
var user = ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username== username);

ViewBag.Items = user.Items.GroupBy(x => x.ItemId).Select(pr => new SalesViewModel
{
 ImageURL = pr.Select(x=>x.ImageURL).FirstOrDefault(),
 Title= pr.Select(x=>x.Title).FirstOrDefault(),
 Sales = pr.Select(x=>x.Transactions.Sum(y=>y.QuantitySold)).FirstOrDefault()
 })
 .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Sales)
 .ToList();
```

So the user object contains a ICollection collection Items which contains 1300 items. And each of these Items contains another ICollection which is called "Transactions" Collection...

I noticed that each of these has like maximum of 20-25 transactions, so the collections inside items isn't so big...

What am I doing wrong here and why is LINQ taking 30-40 seconds to process this code?

Is there any way to make it better??

Comment: The group by is not necessary if `ItemId` is the PK of `Items` table

Comment: @octavioccl it's not unfortunately :(  ... It's a separate property

Comment: I'n guessing from the `ctx` that this is linq for entities? If so use a profiler to see what SQL statements are being generated.

Comment: @stuartd yes correct, okay i shall have a look at that thx :)

Comment: Sounds like N+1 query issue caused by lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your linq query to:

```
var user = ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username== username);

ViewBag.Items = user.Items.GroupBy(x => x.ItemId).Select(pr => new SalesViewModel
{
    ImageURL = pr.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ImageURL),
    Title= pr.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Title),
    Sales = pr.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Transactions.Sum(y=>y.QuantitySold))
})
.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Sales)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Muhammad, how do you actually access the ImageURL/TItle/Transactions Property when you're grouping by an ItemID?

Comment: `pr` is a group, not an `Item`

Comment: You can make it more faster if you require only `IEnumerable` by removing `.ToList()`

Comment: @MuhammadQasim says it cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate

Comment: Your answer uses less code, but is semantically identical, and so won't fix any problems with the original code.

Comment: @Servy is there any reaosn why LINQ performs on even such small collection of 1300 items so slowly?

Comment: @User987 Look at the generated SQL for the query, run profile that query, look at the execution plan, analyze the indexes you're using, or that you might want to have, etc.  See where the bottleneck is in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Approach:

```
var ids = user.Items
    .GroupBy(x => x.ItemId)
    .Where(x=> x.Any())
    .Select(pr => pr.First().Id); /* No ToList yet */

user
    .Items
    .Where(x=> ids.Contains(x.Id)) // <--
    .Select(pr => new SalesViewModel
    {
        ImageURL = x.ImageURL,
        Title= x.Title,
        Sales = x.Transactions.Sum(y=>y.QuantitySold)
    })
    .ToList();
```

The approach is that, read the primary key from the expensive `GroupBy` and use it as a sub-query for the main query. Try this in LINQPad or SSMS to see if this makes a difference.

Comment: It says that the .select doesn't exist in current context?

Comment: @User987 Sorry I updated the answer, the first query now has an extra `Where` and updated `Select`

Comment: For some reason it still says select doesnt exist in current context :D

Comment: @User987 great! let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

As Ivan Stoev wrote in the comments it should be N+1 query issue caused by lazy loading. the answer here is to use the include statement and load the sub entities before you sum the the transactions.

```
var user = ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username== username).Include("Items").Include("Transactions");
```